# Prolog - Sum up "positioned" elem in list

Tags: prolog

I am looking for a solution to the following problem: "Write a Prolog program to sum up all the odd-positioned in a given list."

Sample query:

```
?- odd([1,2,3,4,5],Sum).
Sum = 9.                   % correct as 1+3+5 equals 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct implementation:

```
odd([],0).
odd([X|Xs],S) :- even(Xs,S0), S is S0+X.

even([],0).
even([_|Xs],S) :- odd(Xs,S).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- odd([],S).
S = 0.

?- odd([1],S).
S = 1.
?- odd([1,_],S).
S = 1.

?- odd([1,_,3],S).
S = 4.
?- odd([1,_,3,_],S).
S = 4.

?- odd([1,_,3,_,5],S).
S = 9.
```

Comment: @false. There you are. I hope U like.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of '*odd-positioned*' elements can be found by the following; where lists are indexed from 0:

```
odd_sum_nth0([_,X|Y], Sum) :-
    odd_sum_aux(Y, X, Sum).
```

Else, were lists are indexed from 1:

```
odd_sum_nth1([X|Y], Sum) :-
    odd_sum_aux(Y, X, Sum).
```

Given:

```
odd_sum_aux([_, W|X], Y, Sum) :-
    !, Z is W + Y,
    odd_sum_aux(X, Z, Sum).
odd_sum_aux(_, Sum, Sum).
```

*Caveat emptor*. ;-)

Comment: Nor [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373207/filter-list-prolog/4374962#comment48159961_4374962), nor [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329754/finding-the-longest-contiguous-sublist-in-prolog/26353452#comment48159933_26353452).

Comment: While using a cut, this solution produces clean errors for insufficiently instantiated partial lists.

Comment: ?!? not clear to me what you mean. I discovered your messages (that have been deleted in the meantime) where you talked to me directly and claimed I would downvote you.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like homework, so I'll just give you a nudge in the right direction. The problem is really two separate problems: filter and sum. Solve these separately, and implement odd by composing the solutions.