# Finding the longest contiguous sublist in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm a beginner in Prolog and this is my question:

I have a sorted list of integers without duplicates i.e. `[1,2,3,11,12,13,14,21,22,23,24,25]`

I want to write a predicate that finds the longest contiguous sublist of the elements of the list, that is the longest list where each integer is followed by its subsequent integer (in the set of natural numbers).

In the above example this list would be `[21,22,23,24,25]` where `length = 5`.

In case there are more than one lists with the same maximum length, I'm interested in just one of them, no matter which.

It should work like this:

```
maxCont([1,2,3,11,12,13,14,21,22,23,24,25],Lst]).
Lst = [21,22,23,24,25].
```

Comment: And what did you try ?

Comment: @joel76 Actually, I did find the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655158/longest-increasing-subset-prolog) by changing the first answer's code just a little.

Answer (score 1):

First, we define `z_nonsucc_t/3` based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) and [`bool01_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459595/4609915):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

z_nonsucc_t(X,Y,T) :-
   Y #\= X+1 #<==> B,
   bool01_t(B,T).
```

To split an integer list into consecutive [runs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), we use [`splitlistIfAdj/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) like this:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(z_nonsucc_t,[1,2,3,11,12,13,14,21,22,23,24,25],Pss).   
Pss = [[1,2,3],[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24,25]].
```

Next, we define [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `max_of_by/3` based on [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), [`(#>)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915), and [`(#>=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915):

```
max_of_by(X,[E|Es],P_2) :-
   call(P_2,E,V),
   max_of_by_aux(Es,P_2,V,[E],Rs),
   reverse(Rs,Xs),
   member(X,Xs).

max_of_by_aux([]    , _ ,_ ,Bs ,Bs).
max_of_by_aux([E|Es],P_2,V0,Bs0,Bs) :-
   call(P_2,E,V),
   if_(V #>  V0, Bs1=[], Bs1=Bs0),
   if_(V #>= V0, (V1 = V , Bs2 = [E|Bs1]),
                 (V1 = V0, Bs2 =    Bs1 )),
   max_of_by_aux(Es,P_2,V1,Bs2,Bs).
```

To get the longest list(s), we use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  `max_of_by/3` with  [`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#length) like so:

```
?- max_of_by(Xs,[[1,2,3],[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24,25]],length).
Xs = [21,22,23,24,25].
```

Note that `max_of_by/3` may succeed more than once in tie cases:

```
?- max_of_by(Xs,[[1,2,3],[11,12,13,14,15],[21,22,23,24,25]],length).
  Xs = [11,12,13,14,15]
; Xs = [21,22,23,24,25].
```

Put it all together in predicate `maxCont/2`:

```
maxCont(Zs,Xs) :-
   splitlistIfAdj(z_nonsucc_t,Zs,Pss),
   max_of_by(Xs,Pss,length).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- maxCont([1,2,3,11,12,13,14,   21,22,23,24,25],Xs).
Xs = [21,22,23,24,25].

?- maxCont([1,2,3,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25],Xs).
  Xs = [11,12,13,14,15]
; Xs = [21,22,23,24,25].
```