# Prolog: removing all consecutive integer sublists

Tags: list, prolog, sublist

So I ran into this Prolog problem:

> Given a linear numerical list remove all sequences of consecutive values.
>
> E.g. `remove([1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10], L)` will produce `L=[4, 10]`.

I managed to write this code:

```
consecutive(N,P):-
    N is P-1.

removeS([],[]).
removeS([H],[H]).

removeS([H1,H2],[]):-
    consecutive(H1,H2).
removeS([H1,H2|T],[H1|L]):-
    not(consecutive(H1,H2)),
    removeS([H2|T],L).
removeS([H1,H2,H3|T],L):-
    consecutive(H1,H2),
    not(consecutive(H2,H3)),
    removeS([H3|T],L).
removeS([H1,H2,H3|T],L):-
    consecutive(H1,H2),
    consecutive(H2,H3),
    removeS([H3|T],L).
```

It almost works on some cases like:

```
removeS([1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,11],R). -->  R = [5, 9, 11];
Here only 9 and 11 should be displayed

removeS([3,2,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,11],R). --> R = [3, 2, 5, 9, 11];
Here only 3,2,9,11 should appear in R
```

It's that it takes the last number of an increasing sequence into consideration when it computes the next step.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This is a very good attempt! The reason it doesn't give the answer you want is the last line of the last clause. If `consecutive(H2,H3)` succeeds, then you don't want `removeS([H3|T], L)` since you don't want to count `H3`. You just want `removeS(T, L).`

Comment: @lurker: after applying your 'correction', I get (as expected) `?- removeS([1,2,3,4],L). L = [4]`. Do you have different results ? I insist that  what is missing is generalization...

Comment: @CapelliC I didn't test that case. The "correction" I gave is necessary, but not sufficient. The predicate obviously needs more to make it right. I didn't claim it was a complete solution. It was just something I spotted. I think your answer is an improvement in the direction of refactoring. I was looking for just a patch (answering the question, partially, of "What's wrong with what I have?"). :)

Comment: @lurker: the approach is *logically* flawed: dropping N consecutive elements removes the 'lookahead' required to check following elements! I avoided to post the full code (5 lines !) in hope that Eugen (I agree his is a good attempt) could be interested in discovery the appropriate solution

Answer (score 1):

In this answer we use [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord.html) in combination with two [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)s.

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
```

Based on [`append/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2), [`split_if_adj/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915), [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915), [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), and [`z_nonsucc_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31850246/4609915) we define:

```
consecutives_removed(Xss, Zs) :-
   split_if_adj(z_nonsucc_t, Xss, Yss),
   tfilter(\[_|Xs]^(Xs=[]), Yss, Zss),
   append(Zss, Zs).
```

Sample queries (as given by the OP):

```
?- consecutives_removed([1,2,4,6,7,8,10], Xs).
Xs = [4,10].

?- consecutives_removed([1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,11], Xs).
Xs = [9,11].

?- consecutives_removed([3,2,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,11], Xs).
Xs = [3,2,9,11].
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing less general (and of consequence, more complex) than needed.

```
?- removeS([1,2,3],R).
R = [3] ;
false.
```

I have introduced a service predicate, that 'eats' all consecutives, and simplified the logic to start it *only* when two consecutives appear, and I have:

```
?- removeS([3,2,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,11],L).
L = [3, 2, 9, 11].
```

*edit*

Here is my definition. The cut can be removed, negating the alternative as you have done, but IMHO this only clutter the whole. Or, simply, drop it and wrap removeS/2 top call with once/1.

```
removeS([],[]).
removeS([A,B|T],L):- succ(A,B), eat(A,[B|T],R), !, removeS(R, L).
removeS([A|B],[A|L]) :- removeS(B,L).

eat(A,[B|T],R) :- succ(A,B), eat(B,T,R).
eat(_,T,T).
```

Comment: Although the OP's original approach isn't *totally* logically flawed (I came up with a similar, working solution), your solution is much cleaner and more compact (+1).